# Use volume buttons for camera zooming with camera2 api

Tags: android

I am writing a camera app for android using camera2 api. I need to zoom in and zoom out camera using volume buttons. How can i achieve it?

Answer (score 2):

Use this piece of code. Hopefully it will help.

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{ 
   if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) {
       zoom();
       return true;
   } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) { 
       umzoom(); 
       return true;
   }
   else {
       return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); 
   }
}
```

Zoom and Unzoom Functions

```
public void zoom()
{
    Parameters params=camera.getParameters();
    currentZoom = cameraView.getZoom();

    if(currentZoom != params.getMaxZoom())
       params.setZoom(currentZoom + 1);

    camera.setParameters(params);   
}

public void unzoom()
{
    Parameters params=camera.getParameters();
    currentZoom = cameraView.getZoom();

    if(currentZoom != 0)
       params.setZoom(currentZoom - 1);

    params.setZoom(0);
    camera.setParameters(params);
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to set zoom in between the zero and getMaxZoom() by volume button click e.g. if user keep pressing the volume up key then zoom should go to maximum but if user press button only once and release it then it should increase zoom to specific extent?